# Is it a good idea to use parallel coordinates for visualising outliers?

Tags: python, data, visualization, outlier, plotting

I tried using parallel coordinates to visualize outliers. Is it fundamentally correct?

[image: Parallel coordinates visualizing outliers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scatter plot and box plots are the most preferred for visualizing outliers.

Parallel plots can also be utilized for detecting outliers. For large datasets it can be bit confusing, highlighting outliers comes in handy then.

- [parallel plot case study](http://www.agocg.ac.uk/reports/visual/casestud/brunsdon/parallel.htm)
- [outliers in parallel plot](http://www.agocg.ac.uk/reports/visual/casestud/brunsdon/outliers.htm)

Comment: My data is multi-dimensional with feature values ranging from tens to thousands and I want to visualize whole instances so I can't scatter or box plot. Is parallel coordinates the best choice here?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my answer for large datasets that's the typical choice. You can look into the links I have already provided.